# Autowired not happening for bean with @Async method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to Autowire a bean which contain a @Async method but, it failed with the exception
"Injection of autowired dependencies failed"

My servlet.xml contains the declaration

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="executor" />
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="7"/>
```

Can I get some help why this is failing to autowire ?

--- UPDATE---
Here is the stacktrace of the error.

"cancelAppointment" is the bean id where the Autowire is done for MailService bean

```
2013-08-14 17:06:46,488|main|DEBUG|org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter|Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
2013-08-14 17:06:46,488|main|DEBUG|org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter|Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'executor'
2013-08-14 17:06:46,488|main|INFO|org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor|Shutting down ExecutorService
2013-08-14 17:06:46,492|main|ERROR|org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader|Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cancelAppointment': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ge.appl.service.fs.manager.email.MailService com.ge.appl.service.fs.manager.cancel.consumer.CancelAppointmentImpl.mailService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.ge.appl.service.fs.manager.email.MailService field com.ge.appl.service.fs.manager.cancel.consumer.CancelAppointmentImpl.mailService to $Proxy35
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
```

------ UPDATE 2 ------------
Here is some more detail of the stack trace

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ge.appl.service.fs.manager.email.MailService com.ge.appl.service.fs.manager.cancel.consumer.CancelAppointmentImpl.mailService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.ge.appl.service.fs.manager.email.MailService field com.ge.appl.service.fs.manager.cancel.consumer.CancelAppointmentImpl.mailService to $Proxy35
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.ge.appl.service.fs.manager.email.MailService field com.ge.appl.service.fs.manager.cancel.consumer.CancelAppointmentImpl.mailService to $Proxy35
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:63)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:657)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:498)
    ... 30 more
```

The class where the autowire is done looks like

```
@Component("cancelAppointment")
public class CancelAppointmentImpl extends AbstractCancelAppointment implements
    CancelAppointment {


@Autowired
private MailService mailService;



@Override
public CancelAppointmentCriteria cancelAppointment(
        final CancelAppointmentCriteria criteria) throws Exception {
       // do something
       try {                      
            mailService.sendMail();
           } catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exception
 }
```

}
         }

Comment: Include the stacktrace in your question

Comment: Please add more information, like your stacktrace. Cheers.

Comment: The error is:
    Can not set com.ge.appl.service.fs.manager.email.MailService field com.ge.appl.service.fs.manager.cancel.consumer.CancelAppointmentImpl.mailService to $Proxy35

Please add the code with the @Autowired.

Comment: Here is what my code looks like   @Component("cancelAppointment")
public class CancelAppointmentImpl extends AbstractCancelAppointment implements
  CancelAppointment {

 

 /** The mail service. */
 @Autowired
 private MailService mailService; }

Comment: Is MailService a class or interface?

Comment: MailService is a class

Comment: I had the same case. I had an autowired field and when I add an async on a method, the autowired do not work and return null. 

Things is, after some refactoring, it magically works without making fundamental changes to my classes... Very strange. Did you find anything?

Comment: I spoke too fast. I still have the problem with this error "...Cannot proxy target class because CGLIB2 is not available. Add CGLIB to the class path or specify proxy interfaces."

Answer (score 6):

I'm facing same issue, I think `@EnableAsync` is converting any component using `@Async` to proxy implementing same interfaces used by this component class, so when make autowire with concrete class will face type conflict between this concrete class and proxy, as work around you can use autowire on interface and use `@Qualifier` to specify bean.

Comment: At least in Spring 4, adding @Qualifier(value="beamId") beneath the autowire annotation does not solve the problem described.

Comment: are you making auto-wire on class or interface?